# IE10 - Page loading delayed by CSS Animation

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-10, css-animations

I created an animation to fade out a DIV and then shrink its size down to nothing (since I can't use display: none; in animations). The animation works fine in Google Chrome and FireFox, but in Internet Explorer 10, the page seems to stop loading until the animation completes. So normally the DIV is supposed to appear along with everything else during page load, then after the 3 second delay it should fade out and shrink down so that the rest of the page slides up to fill in the blank space. However, in IE10, the DIV appears, but the rest of the content below the DIV does not... just blank white space. After a few seconds, the content loads just as the DIV starts to fade out.

At first, I thought the 'animation-delay: 3s' was delaying the page from loading too, so I tried changing my animation to not use a delay, and instead just had more keyframes where there was no change to the DIV for the first 0-66%, then 66-88 it would fade out and 88-100 it would shrink. This did not fix the issue and this new animation worked fine again in chrome/firefox but same issue for IE10.

Below is my code. I understand one solution would be to hide the div, and then on page load I could modify the CSS with JavaScript to show the DIV and add the class with the animation... However, I would like to solve this with CSS only, as this animation is used all over the web app I'm developing, so it would add work for anyone using the animation if we used javascript.

Using Asp.Net MVC 4 with razor views, .net 4.5, and Bootstrap CSS

```
NOTE: I used Visual Studio w/ Web Essentials to copy vendor specifics, so all the vendor specific CSS has identical values for everything.

.successFadeOut {
    display: block !important;
    animation: successFadeOutAnimation;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes successFadeOutAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        height: auto;
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }

    70% {
        opacity: 0;
        height: auto;
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        height: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        line-height: 0px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the below code for IE in your class .successFadeOut

```
    -ms-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
```